# Fixing a "Could not read LR from frame..." kernal panic

Tags: kernel-panic

I'm having a Kernal Panic with the following error: `Could not read LR from frame at 0x0000700000080d48`.

How can I resolve this issue?

Is there a way to diagnose the particular kernal issue or faulty program?

**Full Log Output:**

```
Anonymous UUID:       --hidden--

Mon Feb 13 10:53:45 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff801679b084): launchd exited (signal 9, exit status 0 CS_KILLED)

uuid info:
 0x7fff6a497000 uuid = <dc81cc9d-651a-3a45-8809-928282052bd3>
 0x104898000    uuid = <48362449-4519-317e-9a8b-7524036de5ea>

Thread 4 crashed

RAX: 0x0000000104898000, RBX: 0x00007fff6a4d75f8, RCX: 0x00007fff8894b0e8, RDX: 0x00007fff6a4d05c8
RSP: 0x000070000029f740, RBP: 0x000070000029f740, RSI: 0x00000000000001b1, RDI: 0x00007fff6a4d75f8
R8:  0x00007fff8894b119, R9:  0x000070000029fb40, R10: 0x0000000000049c00, R11: 0x00000001048d8170
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x0000000105804040, R14: 0x00000000000001b1, R15: 0x00007fff8894b0e8
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0x00007fff6a4a8882, CS:  0x000000000000002b, SS:  0x0000000000000023

Thread 0: 0xffffff8036f10b60
      Could not read LR from frame at 0x0000700000080d48

Thread 1: 0xffffff8036f0f490
    0x00007fff98810dcd
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 2: 0xffffff8036fe7920
    0x00007fff9881f7b5
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 3: 0xffffff803ba9b490
    0x00007fff9881b675
    0x00007fff9880fa83
    0x00007fff98810200
    0x00007fff98816707
    0x00007fff9880ed53
    0x00007fff9880eb00
    0x00007fff907564de
    0x00007fff90754341
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 4: 0xffffff8046b44b60
    0x00007fff6a4b128b
    0x00007fff6a49b063
    0x00007fff8894b262
    0x00000001048d8170
    0x00000001048c5c28
    0x00007fff9880b40b
    0x00007fff9881b675
    0x00007fff9880fa83
    0x00007fff98810200
    0x00007fff98816707
    0x00007fff9880ed53
    0x00007fff9880eb00
    0x00007fff907564de
    0x00007fff90754341
    0x0000000000000000

Thread 5: 0xffffff804c4ce240
    0x00007fff951c1d69
    0x00000001048c3615
    0x00007fff98823324
    0x00007fff9880b40b
    0x00007fff9881003b
    0x00007fff98816707
    0x00007fff9880ed53
    0x00007fff9880eb00
    0x00007fff907564de
    0x00007fff90754341
    0x0000000000000000

Mac OS version: 15G31
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: B5AA8E3E-65B6-3D0E-867B-8DCCF81E536C
System model name: MacBookPro11,3 (Mac-2BD1B31983FE1663)
Model: MacBookPro11,3, BootROM MBP112.0138.B17, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.19f12
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, PCIe, 2048 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f1 17910, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512F, 500.28 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
```